# PHP fix Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous without change column name

Tags: php, mysql

I have this vode for show result using PHP `join` method:

```
$DB_QUERY = mySqli::f("SELECT name,id, " . AUTHOR . ".id,author_id,book_id  FROM " . AUTHOR . "  JOIN " . AUTHORS . " ON 
" . AUTHOR . ".id = " . AUTHORS . ".author_id WHERE " . AUTHORS . ".book_id = ?  ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 8 ", $id);

foreach($DB_QUERY as $row){
  echo $row['id'];
}
```

Now I see this :

```
 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous
```

I now this error when I have two column with name `id`. how do fix this error without change id name in one column?!

**EDIT:**

author table:

```
id|name|
```

authors table:

```
id|author_id|book_id
```

Comment: A table schema would help, and also explaining the information that you're actually trying to retrieve

Comment: see my edit please ...

Comment: Great, but which ID are you actually trying to retrieve?

Answer (score 1):

```
$DB_QUERY = mySqli::f("SELECT author.name, author.id as a_id, 
authors.id as as_id, authors.author_id, authors.book_id  
FROM author  INNER JOIN authors ON author.id = authors.author_id 
WHERE authors.book_id = ?  ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 8 ", $id);
```

For instance.

Then your field real names haven't changed but in your php you can use their temporary "nicknames" a_id and as_id.

Though I am not sure you need authors.id for anything... if it is only your PK on the table maybe you should drop it and use authors.author_id and authors.book_id as your PK... or.. if you are not bringing content from other tables with it... just don't mention it on your select.

Answer (score 0):

You have selected `id` in your query without any alias & you are applying join on `Author` & `Authors` table. I think as both tables contains id column you are getting the error.

Try this

```
$DB_QUERY = mySqli::f("SELECT name, " . AUTHORS . ".id, " . AUTHOR . ".id,author_id,book_id  FROM " . AUTHOR . "  JOIN " . AUTHORS . " ON 
" . AUTHOR . ".id = " . AUTHORS . ".author_id WHERE " . AUTHORS . ".book_id = ?  ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 8 ", $id);
```